# Is there a way to make a vectorized alpha in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

In ggplot you can change the opacity for each point individually: `ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, fill=Petal.Width, color=Petal.Width, alpha=Petal.Length))`. Is there a way to do that in plotly as well? This does not work:
`plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, color=~Petal.Width, alpha=~Petal.Length)` gives

```
Error in vapply(traces, function(x) x[["alpha"]] %||% 1, numeric(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the opacity is set via the `opacity=` attribute in `plotly` not with `alpha=`. Additionally, the opacity is an attribute of the `marker` attribute. Finally, you have to convert your values manually to the 0 to 1 range for which I use `scales::rescale`. Also note, that different to `ggplot2` you will not get a legend for the opacity.

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly(iris,
  x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Sepal.Length, 
  color = ~Petal.Width,
  marker = list(
    opacity = ~ scales::rescale(Petal.Length, to = c(0, 1))
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this appears not to be working in 3D-Plots? `plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Width, y=~Sepal.Length, z=~Petal.Length, color = ~Petal.Width, marker = list(opacity = ~ scales::rescale(Petal.Length, to = c(0, 1))))`

Comment: According to the [docs](https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatter3d/): *Note that the marker opacity for scatter3d traces must be a scalar value for performance reasons.*, i..e we can't pass a vector. The docs also mention that to set the opacity one has to *set "marker.color" to an rgba color and use its alpha channel.*, i.e. manually create a vector of colors for which you could then set the opacity.